# Running node.js tests against test data in a MongoDB database

Tags: bash, node.js, shell, mongodb

I'm trying to set up a script to execute tests for my node.js program, which uses MongoDB. The idea is that I want to have a script I can run that:

1. Starts the MongoDB process, forked as a daemon
2. Pre populates the database with some test data
3. Starts my node server with forever, so it runs as a daemon
4. Run my tests
5. Drop the test data from the database

I have a crude script that performs all these steps. My problem is that MongoDB takes a variable amount of time to set up, which results in `sleep` calls in my script. Consequently it only works occasionally.

> ```
> # the directory of this script
> DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
>
> # launch mongodb.
> $DIR/../../db/mongod --fork --logpath ./logs/mongodb.log --logappend --dbpath ./testdb/ --quiet 
>
> # takes a bit of time for the database to get set up, 
> # and since we make it a daemon process we cant run the tests immediately
> sleep 1
>
> # avoid EADDRINUSE errors because existing node servers are up.
> killall node &> /dev/null
>
> # start up our node server using a test database.
> forever start $DIR/../main.js --dbname=testdb --logpath=test/logs/testlog.log
>
> # takes a bit of time for node to get set up, 
> # and since we make it a daemon process we cant run the tests immediately
> sleep 1
>
> # run any database setup code (inject data for testing)
> $DIR/../../db/mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/testdb $DIR/setup.js --quiet
>
> # actually run the tests
> node $DIR/tests.js
>
> # kill the servers (this could be a little less heavy handed...)
> killall node &> /dev/null
> killall forever &> /dev/null
>
> # finally tear down the database (drop anything we've added to the test db)
> $DIR/../../db/mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/testdb $DIR/teardown.js --quiet
>
> # and then shut mogodb down
> kill -2 `ps ax | grep mongod | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
> ```

What is the best way to go about what I'm trying to do? Am I going down a rabbit hole here, or am I missing something in the MongoDB docs?

Comment: I don't know anything about node or mongo but in other languages you'd write the code so it wouldn't be dependent on the database.

Comment: Why don't you just sleep longer? what does variable time mean?

Comment: Any reason you can't just keep mongodb running all the time? You're already working with a test db so I don't imagine you'll have conflicting processes.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself what your purpose of your testing is: Is it to test the actual DB connection in your code, or focus on whether your code handles and processes data from the DB correctly?

Assuming your code is in Javascript, if you strictly want to test that your code logic is handling data correctly, and are using a MongoDB wrapper object class (i.e. Mongoose), one thing you may be interested to add to your workflow is the creation and running of spec tests using the [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) test suite.

This would involve writing test-code, mocking-up test data as javascript objects. Yes, that means any actual data from the DB itself will not be involved in your spec tests. Since after all, your primary purpose is to test if your code is logically working right? It's your project, only you know the answer :)

Comment: I never fully understood the reasoning behind removing the DB from the test pipeline. If I can test against an isolated, pre-populated test database that exactly mimics my production configuration and data schemas, isn't that preferable to spending time writing and maintaining mocks?

Answer (score 0):

If your main problem is how to find out when mongod actually starts why don't you write a script which will tell you that ?

For example you can write a until loop and check if the client can connect properly on the mongo server, based on the return value. For example instead of using `sleep 1` use something like that:

```
isMongoRunning=-1

until [[ ${isMongoRunning} -eq 0 ]]; do
        sleep 1
        $DIR/../../db/mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/testdb $DIR/empty.js --quiet
        isMongoRunning=${?}
done
```

This loop will end only after mongodb start.

Also of you would like to improve the stopping of mongodb add `--pidfilepath` to your mongod execution line so you can easily find which process to terminate.